# Hanging swing from back patio roof

Tags: framing, roof, load-bearing, load, porch-swing

My  back patio roof is a flat roof with 2x6 rafters which look to be connected to the house using joist hangers.  The far end of the rafters sit on a 4x12 beam.

With the weight of the swing and people, call it 500-600 lbs, is it ok to hang from 2 rafters?

Or is there concern the joist hangers would fail?

Comment: What does the 4x12 beam sit on?

Comment: The dynamic load or the swing can be much higher than the static weight.

Answer (score -1):

2 x 6 joist hangers are rated for a minimum of 400 lbs load at a 45 deg. angle, slightly more at a shallower angle. So two joists should be good for 800 lbs total.

Or if you are concerned, attach a 1" steel pipe across multiple rafters, then attach the swing to the pipe.

Comment: My read is the 2x6 rafter is a horizontal beam sitting on the 4x12 steel beam at the far end, the OP was asking is it safe to "hang" the swing to it. Without knowing the span length and where in the span of the rafter the swing is hanging, your answer could be dangerous to the user or the roof.